# navigation error during button onPress event

Tags: react-native

I've seen this asked before, but none of the solutions I found on both Stack Overflow and elsewhere helped in my situation.

I am getting this error when clicking the 'Info' button

```
undefined is not an object evaluating (_this.props.navigation)
```

I am not sure why, but I know it has to do with this line in the ChatScreen class:

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
```

The thing I don't get, is that the same line works fine in the HomeScreen class.

So I am not sure how to fix it.

If anyone could offer some advice, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, Button,} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Welcome',
    };
    render() {
        //works
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <View>
                <Button 
                    onPress={ () => navigate('Chat', { user: 'Abe'})}
                    title = "Chat with Abe"
                />
            </View> 
        );
    }
}

class ChatScreen extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const { state, setParams } = navigation;
        const isInfo = state.params.mode === 'info';
        const {user} = state.params;
        //throws the error: undefined is not an object evaluating this.props.navigation
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return {
            title: isInfo ? `${user}'s Contact Info:` : `Chat with ${state.params.user}`,
            headerRight: (
                <Button
                    title={ isInfo ? 'Done' : `${user}'s info` }
                    onPress={ () => navigate('Info', { user: 'Abe' })}
                />

            )
        };
    };

}

class InfoScreen extends React.Component {    
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const {user} = state.params;
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>
                    {user}'s Info
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }  
}

//navigation tabs
const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
});

const NavTest = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: MainScreenNavigator },
    Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
    Info: { screen: InfoScreen }
});

//title
MainScreenNavigator.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'My Chats',
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('NavTest', () => NavTest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're getting the navigation object from `navigationOptions`, you should be able to call navigate on that without having to do this.props.navigation:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { state, setParams, navigate } = navigation;
    const isInfo = state.params.mode === 'info';
    const {user} = state.params;
    return {
        title: isInfo ? `${user}'s Contact Info:` : `Chat with ${state.params.user}`,
        headerRight: (
            <Button
                title={ isInfo ? 'Done' : `${user}'s info` }
                onPress={ () => navigate('Info', { user: 'Abe' })}
            />
        )
    };
};
```

Comment: That gives me a different error: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'inst.render()')